# Дополнительные языковые файлы в другой папке(kohana 3.2) i18n

Tags: i18n, kohana

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите пожалуйста как подключить дополнительный языковой файл из другой папки?

Например в папке i18n у меня есть языковой файл ru.php я хочу что бы к нему так же подключался другой языковой файл из папки application/classes/modules/test_module/i18n/ru.php

и если я например изменю язык, нужно что бы подключаемый файл так же менялся без ручного вмешательства.
Хочу организовать полную локализация cms даже в модулях(своя модульная система)

Заранее благодарю за ответы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Иногда один эксперимент может сберечь от 3 часов ожидания.*

Языковые файлы в `Kohana` подключаются без ручного вмешательства. Читайте про [каскадную файловую систему](http://kohanaframework.su/guide/file_system).

Файлы будут объеденяться.

Comment: Мммм...думаю вы меня не поняли или я вас не понял...вот http://postimg.org/image/6jhccejg1/ особо вариантов решения я тут не вижу, ну кроме как закачать в i18n отдельную папку для каждого модуля, но это будет неудобно...у меня своя модульная система и как я понимаю кохана в ней не будет искать языковые файлы, хотя сейчас в голову пришло немного подправить саму систему что бы она все таки искала там где нужно, но хочется как можно меньше вмешиваться в работу ядра

Comment: Да, я не обратил внимание, что это у вас творится в ``application``.  
Но тут вы сами себе кашу заварили и без ручного вмешательства никак. Модифицируйте ``find_file()``, страдайте :)

Comment: Ну да, немного каша)) честно говоря деликатно решил эту проблему) просто создал метод дубликат find_files в application/classes/kohana.php и прописал там http://paste.ubuntu.com/6467690/ (оставлю на всякий случай, может кому пригодиться...не исключено что мне самому через пару лет)  соглашусь что не слишком красиво но мозга уже после 3х ночи перестала варит) зато все работает и это радует.

Comment: Думаю, не стоило это делать в ``find_files()``, чтобы не выполнять поиск каждый раз. Где-то же у вас происходит подключение модулей - там и дополните ``Kohana::$_paths``.  
В любом случае, дело ваше.

Comment: оу...действительно) Спасибо за совет, сейчас пойду подправлю)